# Are there any English servers where I can play Mahjong online?

Tags: mahjong, online

I recently stumbled upon the Asian game Mahjong and came to like it.  I already play Go and Chess online, but had difficulties finding a good, English-language Mahjong server.

Are there any English servers, and if so what are they?

Comment: You're more likely to find a good answer for this in [Gaming's chat](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic, see http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-questions-purely-about-online-versions-of-a-game-be-allowed/59#59

Comment: @C. Ross: This is a question that may be interesting to many people, so it should be asked on the site and be visible. Imo, Chat is definitely the wrong place for this kind of question.

Comment: As per the question on meta, I believe this question should NOT be closed.

Comment: Nominated to reopen, as per what seems to be the consensus on meta. If you play a board game online, it's still the same game; thus it's still on topic for this SE. If the online game is substantially different, then it would probably be off topic. In this case, the mahjong solitaire that is generally played only on a computer would be off-topic, but mahjong the multi-player gambling game would count as a board or card game and asking about playing it online should too.

Comment: Also voted to reopen, in agreement with @Brian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've played [Mahjong](http://games.yahoo.com/games/login2?page=mjs) online through Yahoo. But, there usually aren't that many players on their server. Yahoo also have [solitaire](http://games.yahoo.com/games/login2?page=mjs) Mahjong games, if that's what you're referring to.

You could also try [MahjongExpress](http://www.mahjongexpress.com/). I've never played on there, but it looks like it requires you to install software, kind of like the online poker games.

Comment: I tried Mahjong Express, it's a nice program with a limited but reasonable set of features. Few players (only around 5-10 players online usually).

Answer (score 5):

A friend notified me of a site he occasionally plays on: http://tenhou.net/

According to him, it's a nice site. Problem is that it's entirely in Japanese. He's lucky enough to understand Japanese but most people don't so I added this answer just for reference.

**Update:** I found [a nice site](http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/mahjong/mahjong_e.html) where you can play (only) against the computer. English language, no setup, completely free and easy to use - a great introduction into Mahjong.

**Update 2:** [This page](http://mahjong.wikidot.com/list-of-online-clients) lists several clients. I did not try them yet.

> - [DragonKong Mahjong](http://www.dragonkong.com/)
> - [Janryumon (雀龍門)](http://janryumon.plaync.jp/)
> - [Japanese Mahjong by Game Design](http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/mahjong/mahjong_e.html)
> - [Kinma Mahjong Online Battle (近代麻雀オンラインバトル)](http://www.kinma.jp/main.php)
> - [Kong 88](https://www.kong88.com/)
> - [MahjongTime](http://www.mahjongtime.com/)
> - [Maru-Jan](http://www.maru-jan.com/)
> - [Pairon (ぱいろん)](http://www.pairon.jp/)
> - [Ron2 (ロン2)](http://www.ron2.jp/)
> - [Tenhou (天鳳)](http://tenhou.net/)
> - [Tetsuya@Tonpuusou (哲也＠東風荘)](http://tetsuya-tonpu.com/)
> - [Tonpuusou (東風荘)](http://mj.giganet.net/)
> - [Toupaiou (闘牌王)](http://www.toupai-ou.com/)
> - [Tsumo (ツモ)](https://www.tsumo.jp/)
> - [Yahoo! Games](http://games.yahoo.com/mj)
> - [Yahoo!ゲーム - 無料ゲーム - 麻雀](http://games.yahoo.co.jp/games/login.html?page=jmj)

Answer (score 1):

I've also fell in love with this game recently. To play against players I am trying out MahjongTime, they give you a certain number of chips to play a day and you can play off of that. (four times a day if you don't win any games) and play for 0 mp

They have different styles of play, Hong kong, Taiwanese, American... etc.

And different rules. Not sure I would trust them for cash games but it is a good relief for quick games.

I don't find it very social though.

http://www.mahjongtime.com/

Comment: Could you add a link?

Comment: mafutrct has a link above but I will edit my post in a few seconds

Comment: Just had a look, nice site though few players

Answer (score 0):

The National Mah Jongg League has an "official" version of American Mah Jong online with a PC based client. It cost an additional $40/year to your membership/card for the league. I have never tried it but it does allow for live online play with the current year's card.

http://www.nationalmahjonggleague.org/
http://www.nmjl.org/software/home.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a new site that supports Chinese (MCR rules): https://playmahjong.io/

It's free to play and you can play bot and multiplayer 4-player games. The in-game UI is quite nice and it's being actively developed.